# Will potatoes discolor if I pre-make scalloped potatoes?

Tags: potatoes

I'm planning to make scalloped potatoes with russet potatoes and cream and cheese.  If I prepare and assemble the dish in the evening, can I store it (covered in the refrigerator) overnight and bake it the next day?  Will the potatoes discolor or soften in the cream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be fine.

We sometimes do it in the morning for dinner and it gives no problem. Just make sure all the potatoes are covered with liquid, or those pieces would discolour.